# unexpected results of a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

Normally this function should give me the values ​​1, 2, 3 or 4. but when I use it, I get 0, 1 or 2. Could you help me to know where is the problem:

```
function Vecteur_retour = var_Test(Test)

AA = Test;

var_Test = zeros(1,2000);

for i=3:1:2000  
     if AA(i)<=AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)<=AA(i-2)  
     var_Test(i)=1;  
     else   
     if AA(i)<=AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)>AA(i-2)  
     var_Test(i)=2;  
     if AA(i)>AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)<=AA(i-2)  
     var_Test(i)=3;  
     else  
     if AA(i)>AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)>AA(i-2)  
     var_Test(i)=4;  


     end   
     end   
     end  
     end  


end  


Vecteur_retour = var_Test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you never reach the cases `var_Test(i) = 3` or `var_Test(i) = 4`.

You have a problem with your `if` and `end` blocks.  The way you have it, case 3 is only reached if case 2 is hit first, but these are contradictory.

You want code more like.

```
 function Vecteur_retour = var_Test(Test)  

 AA = Test;  
 var_Test = zeros(1,2000);  

 for i=3:1:2000        
     if AA(i)<=AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)<=AA(i-2)
         var_Test(i)=1;        
     else
         if AA(i)<=AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)>AA(i-2)
             var_Test(i)=2;
         else  % you forgot this else
             if AA(i)>AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)<=AA(i-2)        
                 var_Test(i)=3;
             else
                 if AA(i)>AA(i-1) && AA(i-1)>AA(i-2)        
                     var_Test(i)=4;          
                 end
             end
         end
     end
 end

 Vecteur_retour = var_Test;
```

Careful indentation would have helped here.

Comment: Or better yet, use the [`elseif`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/elseif.html) keyword.

Comment: Exactly, was trying to keep code as similar as possible to OP's so that they could see the error.

Comment: @ Chris A.    var_Test cases (i) = 3 and var_Test (i) = 4, exist. the case var_Test (i) = 0 does not exist. So there is a problem with the code

Comment: Yes, they exist in your code, but your if then else structure is wrong.  I'll put a comment in my code to show you where.

Comment: @ Chris A.  Ok, thank you Chris, I did not know that the structure is important.

Answer (score 3):

Vector comparisons will be much faster:

```
var_Test = ones(1,2000);

delta_Test = diff(Test);
var_Test([0 0 delta_Test(1:end-1)] > 0) = 2;
var_Test([0 delta_Test] > 0) = var_Test([0 delta_Test] > 0) + 2;
var_Test(1:2) = 0;
```